# C# unsafe code fixed pointer passed as parameter

Tags: c#, fixed, unsafe

I came across the following code on msdn:

```
        unsafe static void SquarePtrParam (int* p) 
        {
            *p *= *p;
        }

        unsafe static void Main() 
        {
            Point pt = new Point();
            pt.x = 5;
            pt.y = 6;
            // Pin pt in place:
            fixed (int* p = &pt.x) 
            {
                SquarePtrParam (p);
            }
            // pt now unpinned.
            Console.WriteLine ("{0} {1}", pt.x, pt.y);
        }
```

I am just wondering, we are directly accessing pointer in `SquarePtrParam` function, does it inherit information that array is fixed from calling method?

Why don't we need to explicitly set it to `fixed` locally in `SquarePtrParam`.

I guess I could use some elaborations about this `fixed` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed statement implement unpin memory area in the same manner as "using" statement close opened files in using(FileStream stream = new FileStream(..)) construction. Memory will be pinned until you left the fixed code block.

In the IL code it will create dummy PINNED local variable and store a pointer into it. This will not allow GC move memory area contains this pointer. After you will left fixed block it will store zero into this PINNED variable. Just like this:

```
public static unsafe void TestInternal(byte* pointer)
{
    Console.WriteLine((IntPtr)pointer);
}

public static void FixedDemo()
{
    Byte[] newArray = new Byte[1024];

    unsafe
    {
        fixed (Byte* pointer = &newArray[0])
        {
            TestInternal(pointer);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Test Complete");
}
```

So FixedDemo in IL Code:

```
.method public hidebysig static void  FixedDemo() cil managed
{
  // Code size       47 (0x2f)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] uint8[] newArray,
           [1] uint8& pinned pointer)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4     0x400 // Put 1024 on the stack
  IL_0006:  newarr     [mscorlib]System.Byte // allocate new array of 1024 length
  IL_000b:  stloc.0    // Store it in local variable 0
  IL_000c:  nop 
  IL_000d:  ldloc.0    // Put local variable 0 on the stack
  IL_000e:  ldc.i4.0   // Put zero on the stack
  IL_000f:  ldelema    [mscorlib]System.Byte // Load address of zero index from array
  IL_0014:  stloc.1    // !!! Here we pin memory by storing it in pinned variable
  IL_0015:  nop
  IL_0016:  ldloc.1    // Load function argument
  IL_0017:  conv.i     // Perform conversion 
  IL_0018:  call       void FinMath.Tests.Program::TestInternal(uint8*)
  IL_001d:  nop
  IL_001e:  nop
  IL_001f:  ldc.i4.0   // Load zero on the stack
  IL_0020:  conv.u     // Perform conversion 
  IL_0021:  stloc.1    // !!!! Here we unpin memory
  IL_0022:  nop
  IL_0023:  ldstr      "Test Complete" // Load string
  IL_0028:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string) // Out message
  IL_002d:  nop
  IL_002e:  ret
} // end of method Program::FixedDemo
```

For more information visit:

1. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
2. [MSDN Magazine: Garbage Collection: Automatic Memory Management in the Microsoft .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx)
3. [Common language Runtime standard ECMA 335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) Partition III, 1.1.4.2 Managed Pointer (type &)

Answer (score 1):

> does it inherit information that array is fixed from calling method?

No, it doesn't need that information. All it knows is that it's been passed a pointer. One way of obtaining a pointer is via the `fixed` statement, but there are other ways (e.g. by converting an IntPtr), and any such compatible pointers could also be passed to `SquarePtrParam`.

Comment: tbh I like this answer too cause really once method got pointer as parameter it doesn't really care much about other stuff.