# What exactly is 'fixed' doing?

Tags: c#, .net

I have some code that looks like this, in an unsafe context:

```
 ValidatePartialOperation(array, startingOffset, runLength);

 fixed (double* _op = array)
 {
     double* op = _op + startingOffset;
     callSomething(op, runLength);
 }
```

And I have that copy+pasted in a couple of different places.  But I hate having that kind of validation and pointer arithmetic in multiple places, so I'd like to combine together the logic in to a single line that looks something like:

```
 double* op = preCall(array, startingOffset, runLength);
 callSomething(op, runLength);
 postCall(array);
```

Or even better:

```
 using (double* op = preCall(array, startingOffset, runLength))
 {
     callSomething(op, runLength);
 }
```

But whatever happens I can't afford to lose performance from the 'fixed' version.

My plan right now is to mimic what the fixed statement is doing, but I don't actually know what that is.  Presumably some try-catch block with a pinning operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for future readers, I think I've pretty well figured it out, though with a few educated guesses.

Basically it seems that `fixed` is the C# way to invoke the C++/CLI [pin_ptr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1dz8byfh.aspx).  These are special variables that must be declared as local variables on the stack.  They don't seem to communicate with the GC directly, so they're very light weight.  Instead, when the GC runs it's smart enough to scour the callstacks of all active threads and check to see if any functions' variables are these special pinning pointers.  If they are, whatever they point at is marked as pinned and won't be moved in memory during garbage collection.

By comparison, `GCHandle.Alloc(obj, GCHandleType.Pinned)` actually communicates with the GC and places the object in a list of objects not to be moved.  Which means every time you `GCHandle.Alloc` and then `Free`, you're adding and removing elements to the list and doing work.  Pinning pointers are an entirely passive mechanism and don't need to do any extra work.  That also explains why you can't change the value of a fixed pointer: the managed object it points to is only guaranteed to be fixed as long as the fixed pointer points to it.  And if the fixed pointer pointed to a different object, *it* would now be pinned instead.  And if you set the fixed pointer to null, even for just a moment, it would no longer be pinning anything and all pointer math you've done so far would be invalidated.

Which explains the performance hit when I tried to switch to GCHandles.  So `fixed` isn't just the best tool, it's the *only* tool, at least when performance is important.  Even if the syntax is sometimes awkward.

Answer (score 5):

Sure, you can do that. Whether it will meet your performance needs, I don't know; you should measure and find out.

To fix an array in place and obtain a pointer without using the `fixed` statement you can use a `GCHandle` object. Call `GCHandle.Alloc` with the "pinned" handle type, passing in the array and you'll get back an `IntPtr` which you can safely cast to a pointer. The array will stay pinned until `Free` is called on the `GCHandle`, so *make sure you do not lose track of the `GCHandle`*. You are wrecking garbage collector performance as long as that handle is outstanding.

But my advice is to use the `fixed` statement. That's what it's for.

Comment: I've tried this just now, and the code is _much_ nicer to read, but it seems to be adding significant overhead (~50% slower, or about an extra 1 second on my test case that normally runs in 3).  Looking in a profiler, it seems that GCHandle.Free is causing most of the added overhead.  I'm guessing 'fixed' is using a different mechanism, then?

Comment: @JayLemmon: "fixed" emits special code in the IL that tells the runtime directly that a local variable refers to a pinned reference. How the jitter deals with that in turn I do not know.

Comment: Hmm... looking at the IL in eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095140/c-sharp-unsafe-code-fixed-pointer-passed-as-parameter it looks like the actual pinning happens by having a specially marked local variable hold on to the address.  Presumably the GC is smart enough to look through the callstacks for these special local variables and do its pinning that way.  Since I can't directly play with these mechanisms in C# except through fixed, it looks like I'm stuck using that syntax :/  There's probably a way to hack some IL and inject it, but I don't want to work that hard.

Comment: @JayLemmon Why can't you use `GCHandle.Alloc()` instead, just like Eric mentioned?

Comment: @svick: Because apparently allocating the handles yourself is slower.

Answer (score 0):

fixed is preventing the garbage collector from relocating your object during memory compacting. If you don't use it, then your object can be moved at any time and pointer will became invalid.

Comment: And how exactly do you get that pointer without using `fixed`?

Answer (score 0):

No, nothing like that. Like MSDN says: [Fixed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) statement prevents garbage collector to move memory, so that your fixed pointer stays valid as long as it needs to. This is important if you are working with some unmanaged resources. To my current knowledge you cannot substitute it with any `using`, `try/catch/finally` or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

[`fixed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) pins the variable, preventing the garbage collector from moving the object for the duration of the `fixed` block.

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The C# compiler only lets you assign a pointer to a managed variable in a fixed statement.

Thus, it seems you may not be able to work around using the `fixed` statement in your code.